# Как правильно сделать POST запрос с JSON данными для таблицы datatables.net?

Tags: javascript

Использую для работы с таблицами компонент [datatables.net](https://datatables.net).

```
$('#nocTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: "/Jobs/GetIncomingNoc",
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        data: function ( json ) {
            return json.ID = 10;
        },
        contentType: "application/json"
    },
    columns: [
        {achTransactions: "transactionId"},
        {achTransactions: {
            _: "transactionDate.year"
        } }
    ]
} );
```

При этом в Request Payload показывает:

```
[object Object]
```

Подозреваю, что проблема в

```
    data: function ( json ) {
        return json.ID = 10;
    }
```

Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Рабочим вариант:

```
$('#nocTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "/Jobs/GetIncomingNoc",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: function () {
            return JSON.stringify({ID: 10});
        },
        dataSrc: "achTransactions",
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "transactionId" },
        {achTransactions: {
            _: "transactionDate.year"
        } }
    ]
});
```

Суть в том, чтобы в `data` передать функцию которая создаёт валидную json строку:

```
        data: function () {
            return JSON.stringify({});
        },
```